# Workflow when creating a Windows Phone App, Expression Blend and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xaml, expression-blend

I'm busy with a Windows Phone 7 application using Visual Studio 2010 only. I've read that one can also use Expression Blend to develop the app. But there a few things that I'd like to clear up regarding how one works with both these applications when developing an app.

Firstly I know how it works in Visual Studio, you can create the UI with xaml code, and then add interactivity with your C# code. So what exactly is Expression blend for? Is it more geared toward designing the interface and not so much interactivity? Can you do interactivity in Expression blend at all?

From what I can gather (again I'm not sure about this), one works with both these applications. Expression Blend for the UI, and Visual Studio for the back-end/interactivity. Is this correct?

Assuming that the above is correct. How do you go about this? Can you work on the same solution in both programs? What would your typical workflow be like when working on both these programs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct; Visual Studio is used primarily to write the code that makes the programs work, while Blend is used to design the UI. Blend primarily works by dragging UI elements into their desired position, though you can also directly manipulate the XAML if you wish, or both, even.

You can edit the code-behind in Blend, but you'll be missing a lot of functionality Visual Studio offers in that department.

You can have the same solution open in both Blend and Visual Studio and switch between them as needed, but changes to either won't be picked up by the other until you save the modified files.

Personally, I use Visual Studio for the coding, and Blend for the design. Both open at the same time, with the same solution loaded.

Comment: What are the main benefits of designing the UI in Blend instead of using VS for both? VS also has a drag drop system for designing the UI. I've tried to use both programs as you described in the past but couldn't see much advantage in doing so, so I currently use VS for UI and code behind. Just something I wanted clearing up.

Comment: @J.B I find designing the UI in Blend easier, and Blend has a lot more options. For example, you cannot easily do storyboard animations in Visual Studio, or create item templates. Blend's UI is more organized and aimed towards UI design, whereas Visual Studio is designed mainly to do code, and that shows, especially if you compare Visual Studio's Property pane with Blend's. I also find rearranging child controls easier to do in Blend than in Visual Studio. In the end, I guess it's mainly a matter of preference.

Comment: ahh I see thank you. I will have to give it another try at some point. Guess I just got used to doing things in VS, even if Blend was actually better. Out of interest, does it help with setting up GUIs for different form factors, and if so how? Its one thing that I still haven't completely got to grips with yet.

Comment: @J.B If with different form factors, you mean, for example, for Windows and Windows Phone, then yes. If you've installed the Windows Phone developer tools, Phone-specific templates will be added to Blend to help design your app's UX, Whereas by default Blend comes with templates for WPF and SilverLight.

Comment: by form factors I meant different size screens, e.g. making an app for a windows 8 tablet, then using it on a windows 8 27" desktop. does blend help in designing layouts more suited to different screens? Sorry if this is an obvious or basic question, but honestly in my relatively limited experience I have never come across a clear process of designing the same app for different screen sizes. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @J.B Ah, I see what you mean. If you're developing for multiple form factors, you're best off using a mix of absolute- and proportional sizes for your layout. I.E. have your menu be of a fixed size, and use an '*' to proportionally fill the remaining space. Out of the box, neither Blend, nor Visual Studio offers any specific help with this.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much. It is a shame that there is no easier way to specify designs for different sized screens, though your approach makes sense, many thanks.